# mysql query order by

Tags: wp-query, query, mysql

I'm new to mysql.

I've got this query:

```
$tenantsInfo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM exp_ten WHERE tenant_number = " . (int) $user->ID);
```

I need to order it by desc;
Due to double-quotes I'm not sure where to add order by desc. Can please anyone point me out where should I add it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tenantsInfo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM exp_ten WHERE tenant_number = " . (int) $user->ID ." ORDER BY DESC");
```

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to use the codex if you get stuck [link]https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb[/link] - Please accept my answer :)

Comment: Accepted :) but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation so my vote isn't visible, but thanks again:)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)